# parametrization the curve $x^2=4ay$

Tags: differential-geometry

How can I able to parametrize the curve $x^2=4ay$ such that it becomes a
($i$) it becomes a regular curve.
($ii$)the parametrization becomes a unit speed parametrization.

Actually I want to find the signed curvature of the parabola given curve.To do so I need to parametrize it and exactly where I have stuck.

Can I get some help?

Comment: what do you mean 'regular'? what is exotic about the curve guven?

Comment: If $\gamma(t)$ is a parametrized curve then it is call regular if $\gamma'(t) \ne 0$

Comment: Parametrize by $x=2at,y=at^2$ (and assume $a\neq 0$).

Answer (score 0):

Georges' parametrization is fine, but you won't find a unit speed parametrization in simple terms.  Fortunately you don't need it, but you want to find the curvature $\kappa$ of the curve $c(t):=(2at,at^2)$ instead. Now that's given by 
$$\kappa=\frac{\det(c',c'')}{\|c'\|^3}.$$
You might find [How to reparametrize curves in terms of arc length when arc-length evaluation cannot be computed analytically](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683039/how-to-reparametrize-curves-in-terms-of-arc-length-when-arc-length-evaluation-ca/683230#683230) helpful as well.