# Polynomial parametrized curve exact length - Computational way

Tags: differential-geometry, polynomials

I currently try to understand differential geometry from an undergraduate perspective. Given curve $\gamma$ in space parametrized rather by its length or any other scalar, consider the dimension it pleases you, its  length is given by $\int\limits_{0}^{s_f} \| \gamma'(s) \| \, ds$. The absolute value is given by the inner product or, in a geometric sense, the metric of the space, which by R^n and 2-norm, is a square root. For simplicity, consider euclidean space. Therefore, I wonder if there is a generic way to compute the exact algebraic solution for $\int\limits_{0}^{s_f} \sqrt{f(s)} \, ds$, in this case, f(s) a positive polynomial function, for example.

Comment: No, there isn't, unfortunately.  Practically this parametrisation is often not needed, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683039/how-to-reparametrize-curves-in-terms-of-arc-length-when-arc-length-evaluation-ca/683230#683230.

Comment: Aff, then the best way is numerically fine-discretized mesh?! Boring.

Comment: For what purpose do you need arc length?

Comment: It was an idea I had to obtain the path for a mobile robot (the unicycle) between two given configurations. If you think a little, the pol degree depends on how many points are available to interpolate.

Comment: To avoid strange paths, one prefer the shortest path, which means to minimize the curve length.

Comment: The free parameters are constrained by the optimization statement

Comment: In your case there will numerical methods needed.  There's no closed form for arc length of a generic polynomial.