# why we don't divide numerator by vector length in directional derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

why directional derivative alongside v vector is defined such a way:    $\lim_{t \to +\ 0 } {\dfrac{f(x_0+t\cdot v)-f(x_0)}{t}}$, and not such a way:
$\lim_{t \to +\ 0 } {\dfrac{f(x_0+t\cdot v)-f(x_0)}{t\cdot||v||}}$.I mean why we don't divide numerator by ||v||?It would be more intuitive and explainable if we had defined directional derivative such a way.rate of change divided by length of the change.

Comment: You are right, but it is usually implied that $||v||=1$ so that it is a direction.

Comment: Both are used in the literature. Unfortunately these are two confliciting definitions of directional derivatives.

Comment: thank you.can you give me name of book or something, where author defines directional derivative in different way(i mean dividing by ||v||)?

Comment: The derivative with respect to $v$ is meant to describe the infinitesimal rate of change of $f$ when you start moving from $x_0$ with speed $v$. Surely if $v$ is twice longer, that rate is twice higher.

Comment: i know it is obvious, difference is only positive constant, but why?I knew directional derivative earlier and now my professor tells me different thing.I think it would be more convenient if we had defined derivative according to my suggestion(dividing by length).

Comment: Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683039/how-to-reparametrize-curves-in-terms-of-arc-length-when-arc-length-evaluation-ca/683230#683230 is of help.

Comment: Convenient for what purposes? For instance, **not** normalizing the direction vector leads to a rather nice coordinate-free definition of a tangent space.

Comment: Have you ever seen a vector described as having a "direction and a magnitude" (or "direction and length")? Take any arbitrary non-zero vector $v$; then $\| v\|$ is its magnitude (or length) and what's left when you divide $v$ by its magnitude is its direction, $v/\|v\|$, which is always a unit vector. So what is _convenient_ (I think) is to decide that every direction vector is a unit vector. That way we don't have two different vectors like $(1,0)$ and $(2,0)$ for the same direction.

Comment: Now if someone refers to $\lim_{t \to +\ 0 } {\dfrac{f(x_0+t\cdot v)-f(x_0)}{t}}$ as a "directional derivative" I agree it is confusing, because this is really more than just a directional derivative.